# How to show the titles of subplots on box plots done using Groupby?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby, boxplot

I just created box plots using a groupby, however, I'm having trouble including the titles of each box plot. Just to clarify, I don't manually want to change the titles of the subplots, I would like it to be automatically displayed since right now I just get all of the plots but I have no idea which is for what group...

Here's an example: 
[image: Example]

Here's the code I'm using:

```
gt_venta_precio_zona = gt_venta[['Precio USD','Zona']]
gt_venta_precio_zona.groupby('Zona').plot.box(fontsize=20,rot=90,figsize=(12,8),return_type='axes',patch_artist=True)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the grouped data and then iterate over the groups, supplying the group name (key in [`groups`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups).keys()) as title to the plot function:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {'col1': pd.np.repeat(list('ABCD'), 50), 'col2': pd.np.random.random(200)})

grp = df.groupby('col1')
for key in grp.groups.keys():
    grp.get_group(key).plot.box(title=key)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Stef, this worked perfectly. Exactly what I needed. Thank you for your support!